# Fatal error due to memory size

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mysqli, out-of-memory

I am using CodeIgniter for development. I am getting this error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 1092 bytes) in
>   /home/project_name/public_html/system/libraries/Session.php on line
>   672

To solve this I have increased the memory limit by using this command.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Also I've set the memory limit to `512M` in the `php.ini`

Then also I get this error.

Comment: add it `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` this code make memory limit unlimited.

Comment: Is it a good approach. Will it not affect anything else? Any other workaround for this?

Comment: What does phpinfo() tell you is the effective memory limit? Just want to make sure you've edited the correct ini file.

Comment: @moopet : Memory limit shows 512M

Comment: What were you doing to get need that much memory?

Comment: I had a need of maintaining the ids from previously loaded pages in a session. On every page load the new results should not belong to the previously fetched ids. Only new records should be fetched from the db. These ids I am maintaining in a string format. On adding this code I have noticed this problem. But I get the error on the first page load